# Using Java Pattern Regex to extract information from decoded mailto in WebViewClient

Tags: java, android, regex, android-webview, webviewclient

I use android API 19 to embed website in webview and here i face this problem that when a user click link mailto. I want to extract information and start ACTION_SEND intent.

```
String firstUrl = "mailto:abc@test.com.kh";
String secondUrl = "mailto:abc@test.com.kh?subject=Request%20to%20create%20a%20new%20listing&body=To%20create%20or%20update%20your%20listing%20on%20cambodiastaging.yoolk.com";
```

So i want to match and get data like this.

```
email    #=> abc@test.com.kh
subject  #=> Request%20to%20create%20a%20new%20listing
body     #=> To%20create%20or%20update%20your%20listing%20on%20cambodiastaging.yoolk.com
```

Here are my attempts.

```
"^mailto:(^?)\\?{0,1}" #=> group1=abc@test.com.kh for both url
```

The best answer I'm looking for is a regex pattern that match:

- "mailto:abc@test.com.kh2"
- "mailto:abc@test.com.kh?subject=Request%20to%20create%20a%20new%20listing&body=To%20create%20or%20update%20your%20listing%20on%20cambodiastaging.yoolk.com"
- "mailto:mailto:abc@test.com.kh?body=body&subject=subject"
- "mailto:mailto:abc@test.com.kh?body=body&subject=subject&cc=abc@me.com&bcc=aaa@me.com"

Answer (score 1):

If your `secondUrl` is always going to be in the same format (mailto , subject, body), you can use `String.split()` thrice.

1. Split `secondUrl` first with a `?` and get the first element. It will be the email ID.
2. Take [1]th element of the above step and split again using `&`. Now, [0]th element will be subject, and the other element will be body.

   `String mailId = secondUrl.split("\\?")[0];
   String subject = secondUrl.split("\\?")[1].split("&")[0];
   String body = secondUrl.split("\\?")[1].split("&")[1];`

Comment: Yes, but it is not the best answer i look for. I want it to be flexible because mailto links are different from each other. Like order of "subject" and "body".

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer, but i got this working for now for my url pattern above.

```
String mailToRegexp = "^mailto:([^?]+)\\?{0,1}(?:subject=(.+)&body=(.+)){0,1}";
Pattern mailToPattern = Pattern.compile(mailToRegexp);
Matcher mailToMatcher = mailToPattern.matcher(url);

if (mailToMatcher.find()) {
     String email = mailToMatcher.group(1);
     String subject = mailToMatcher.group(2);
     String body = mailToMatcher.group(3);

     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     intent.setType("message/rfc822");
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {email});
     if (subject != null) {
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, URLDecoder.decode(subject));
     }
     if (body != null) {
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, URLDecoder.decode(body));
     }

     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Email To:"));
}
```

This regex will break if pattern url change order of "subject" and "body" or add more like "cc".